# How do I ensure that two modules use the same string cache?

Tags: python-polars

I'd like to have polars dataframes in multiple modules use the same string cache, but I'm finding it difficult to manage. Imagine I have a package with modules `A` and `B`:

```py
# A.py
import polars as pl

df_A = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': pl.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=pl.Category)
})
```

```py
# B.py
import polars as pl

df_B = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': pl.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=pl.Category),
    'B': pl.Series(['d', 'e', 'f'], dtype=pl.Category)
})
```

```py
# __init__.py

from . import A, B

pl.toggle_string_cache(True)

df_C = A.df_A.join(B.df_B, on='A')
```

```
exceptions.ComputeError: joins/or comparisons on categoricals can only happen if they were created under the same global string cache
```

This works if I move the `import` after the call to `pl.toggle_string_cache(True)`, but this is bad code design: imports should always come first. I can think of moving `A.df_A` and `B.df_B` into global variables with generator functions, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: The other solution i can think about is to cast the columns to Utf8 and then cast them back to Categorical in the main program, after activating the String cache. That will make sure they have the same string cache. The negative aspect of it is the additional processing time for the casting

Comment: Thanks Luca. I think I've settled on simply making sure to call `pl.toggle_string_cache(True)` at the beginning of each module, that seems to work.

Comment: Good you found a solution. I am curious if it still works if you don’t set it in the init.py, I will check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simplest answer is to simply ensure that the call to `pl.toggle_string_cache(True)` is made in each module that creates categorical data. In other words, the solution to the original post would be:

```py
# A.py
import polars as pl

pl.toggle_string_cache(True)

df_A = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': pl.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=pl.Category)
})
```

```py
# B.py
import polars as pl

pl.toggle_string_cache(True)

df_B = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': pl.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=pl.Category),
    'B': pl.Series(['d', 'e', 'f'], dtype=pl.Category)
})
```

```py
# __init__.py
from . import A, B

pl.toggle_string_cache(True)

# now this works properly
df_C = A.df_A.join(B.df_B, on='A')
```